# Returning elements consecutively in a row

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns elements **consecutively in a row**  so for instance, If there are 4 **'green'** elements consecutively in a row, **the Function** should return the string: **'Green Wins'**

```js
['green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue'] // -->it should return 'Green wins'
```

otherwise, it should return **'Draw'**

```js
const consecutive  = arr => {
  for(let i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === 'green' && arr[i+1] === 'green' && arr[i+2] === 'green' && arr[i+3] === 'green') {
      return 'Green Wins'
    }
    if(arr[i] === 'blue' && arr[i+1] === 'blue' && arr[i+2] === 'blue' && arr[i+3] === 'blue') {
      return 'Blue Wins'
    }
  }
  return 'Draw';
}

let greenWins = consecutive(['green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue']);
console.log(greenWins); // --> 'Green Wins'
```

This is the code that solves it, but it's kind of repetitive, that's why I'm asking your help if we could solve it with something like **reduce method**?

```js
 const consecutive  = arr => {
 for(let i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] === 'green' && arr[i+1] === 'green' && arr[i+2] === 'green' && arr[i+3] === 'green') {
     return 'Green Wins'
   }
   if(arr[i] === 'blue' && arr[i+1] === 'blue' && arr[i+2] === 'blue' && arr[i+3] === 'blue') {
     return 'Blue Wins'
   }
 }
 return 'Draw!';
}

let greenWins = consecutive(['green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue']);
console.log(greenWins); // --> 'Green Wins'
```

Comment: This is more a code review question and, as such, is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it's not exactly a review question, i'm asking for a different solution.

Comment: What's the wining criteria? how many consecutive occurrences are needs to find a winner? Is it always 4?

Comment: 4 'green' elements consecutively in a row, its on the post.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a counter and a value for the last color ach check and exit early if four consecutive same colors/values are in the array.

```js
let array = ['green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue'],
    counter = 0,
    color,
    check = v => {
        if (v === color) return ++counter === 4;
        counter = 1;
        color = v;
    };

if (array.some(check)) console.log(color, 'wins');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to separate out the logic of "How many consecutive colours" from the logic of "Winning".

```js
const input = ['green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue'] // -->it should return 'Green wins'

const consecutive = arr => {
  return arr.slice(1).reduce( (acc,x,i) => {
    if( x == arr[i] ) {
      acc[x]++
    }
    else {
      acc[x] = 1
    }
    return acc
  },{[arr[0]]:1})
}

var result = consecutive(input);
if(result.green >= 4) {
  console.log("Green wins")
}else if (result.blue >= 4){
  console.log("Blue wins")
} else{
  console.log("Draw")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple use of for loop may solve this,

```js
function checkConsecutivity(srcArray) {

  let count = 1,
    curColor = srcArray[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < srcArray.length; i++) {

    if (curColor == srcArray[i]) {
      count++;
      if (count == 4)
        return curColor + ' wins';
    } else {
      count = 1;
      curColor = srcArray[i]
    }
  }

  return 'Draw';
}

const input = ['green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue'];

console.log(checkConsecutivity(input))
```